# git merge conflict - where is the history

Tags: git

When I was rebasing, I got merge conflict. Then I do the manual fix and then *git add; git rebase --continue*,

but new conflict keep coming up, prompt hint: *Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch*

so I show-current-patch to see

```
index 1hash..8hash 100644
--- a/path/file
+++ b/path/file
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@

+import lib

@@ -11,7 +12,7 @@ project_id = something
 with models.DAG(
 
-    start_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31),
+    start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
```

But if I edit the file in conflict, it is like

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
=======
start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0)
>>>>>>> other guy's commit
```

seems the head content is different from git am --show-current-patch?

I just couldn't figure out where is the value "1" in airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1) coming from?

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which one do you want?   You need replace those 5 lines and keep the one you want, then commeit.

Comment: "but new conflict keep coming up" Not at all unusual during rebase, so what exactly is the issue? Just keep resolving each as it arises.

Comment: "I just couldn't figure out where is the value "1" in airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1) coming from?" Well it tells you, doesn't it? It comes from HEAD, which is the current commit being rebased.

Comment: @matt, I think yout wording is not correct in his last sentence.... and given the nature of the question, I think it's better to clarify. During a rebase, HEAD is the current temporary result of applying on top of the _base_ branch whatever successful revisions have been rebased already. The fact that the line is in HEAD in a conflict during a rebase means one of 2 things: the line was introduced on the base branch before the rebase started. The other possibility is that it was introduced by a rebased revision _and_.....

Comment: .... there is a missing commit in the rebase that changes it (a merge commit and not using --rebase-merges? One revision that you are not rebasing on purpose? Hard to tell _for us_ on this side of the screen). _Probably_, it is a line coming from the base branch.... but there are exceptions. How can we be sure? `git blame` the file and see where that line is coming from.

Comment: @matt, I meant, "I think wording is not correct in your last statement."

Comment: Side note: if your Git mentions using `git am` while you're in the middle of rebase, you have a rather old version of Git. You might want to upgrade it.

Comment: yes I realised my concept was confused.. the value "1" came from my HEAD. Thanks for all the inputr!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two steps when running `git rebase master` from branch `feature` (*) :

```
# before rebase:
*--M--x--y--z <-master
    \
     a--b--c--d <- HEAD, feature

# during rebase, when about to apply commit 'c':
          master
            v
*--M--x--y--z--a'--b' <- HEAD
    \
     a--b--c--d <- feature
```

When replaying commit `c` :

1. the patch being applied is the diff between `b` and `c`
2. but conflicts may arise because of changes in `x, y, z, a' or b'`

If a conflict happens :

- the patch in `1.` will appear as "theirs" ("other guy's commit")
- "ours" will come from "HEAD", and that part does not appear in `1.`

If you want to view what brought the changes in "HEAD", you can inspect `git log -p`, or use `git blame`.

---

(*) or, similarly, if you are running `git format-patch --stdout master..feature | git am` to apply the changes from `feature` on top of `master`